# Default dialer on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, phone-app, default-applications

I have a new Samsung Galaxy S3 running ICS (4.0.4). I would like to use the Go Dialer as my default dialer.

The stock Phone app does not claim to be the default dialer, and in fact I've downloaded Default App and set the default dialer to be the Go Dialer. And yet, when I navigate through a contact to the "dial" press, it brings up the stock Phone app.

I've seen conflicting reports on whether this is possible or not. Is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any dialer customize the things that are come before you press dial button. After pressing the dial button it can only use the stock interface.

Answer (score 2):

The Contacts app and the phone app work as one, however the contacts app *should* allow you to make a call using any app that uses the call broadcast receiver.

Ensure that the standard Phone/Dialer app isn't set as default:

1. Uninstall set default
2. Go into `Settings->Apps->All->Dialer (or Phone)` scroll down and select `Clear Defaults`.
3. Go back into the contacts app, and select a Contact to call. It should ask you which app you want to use. Select `Go Dialer` and select to always use that by default.

Comment: So I did all that (I assume item 1 means to remove the Default App app, which I did). Now both the stock Phone , the stock Dialer, and Go Contacts say they are not the default for any actions. And yet when I select a Contact to call it simply uses the stock Phone app. Sigh.

Comment: @rogerl Please uninstall Go Dialer, and any other custom apps, reinstall and try again.

Comment: When you say "any other custom apps" you really mean "any", or just "any related to dialing and the like"? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, mis-type. I meant custom dialer apps :)

Comment: Yeah, so this made no difference. Even when I go through Go Contacts it brings up the stock Phone app.

Do you actually have a Samsung Galaxy and made this work?

Comment: Strange - could be a bug with Go Contacts, or with your ROM. It *may* be some strange security feature...

Comment: Well, that really bites. It worked fine on my old Droid X. Do you have this phone, or some other?